# Multi target regression with CatBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, catboost, catboostregressor

I am doing a multi-target regression using Catboost. Following is the code:

```
target_col = ['SISU_LP', 'SISU_AM', 'SISU_EP', 'SISU_HR', 'SISU_HS', 'SISU_HO']
text_cols=['surrender','feelings']
X = data.drop(columns=target_col)
y = data[target_col]
params = {'learning_rate': 0.1, 'depth': 6, 
      'loss_function': 'MultiRMSE',  'eval_metric': 'MultiRMSE'}
model = CatBoostRegressor(**params)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
pool_train = Pool(data=X_train, label=y_train,text_features = text_cols)
pool_test = Pool(data=X_test, label=y_test, text_features = text_cols)
model.fit(pool_train, eval_set=pool_test, use_best_model=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Attempt to use multi-dimensional target as one-dimensional
```

The source of the error is `model.fit()`.